# Obtain token transfer data from an address

Tags: tokens, etherscan, explorers, external-api

I would like to obtain token transfer data from an address via Rest API

For example, take this address:
https://etherscan.io/address/0xfbb1b73c4f0bda4f67dca266ce6ef42f520fbb98#tokentxns

(Etherscan doesn't answer support questions about their API "because its free and presented as is", and they don't seem to have an API endpoint to show that same data.)

That link shows all of the token transfers for that address.

I would like to see all token transfers of X for that address. X being a token of my choice.

What is involved with obtaining that data via API?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about using Etherscan's [Event Log API](https://etherscan.io/apis#logs)?

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=logs&action=getLogs
    &fromBlock=0
    &toBlock=latest
    &address=[Token Contract Address]
    &topic0=0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef
    &topic1=[From Address, padded to 32 bytes - optional]
    &topic2=[To Address, padded to 32 bytes - optional]
```

In the above `topic0` is the signature of an ERC20 `Transfer` event.

For example, the [following link](https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=logs&action=getLogs&fromBlock=0&toBlock=latest&address=0xd25e81504e0aea1e1343d61581296bc3c460978b&topic0=0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef&topic1=0x000000000000000000000000376d5c3a16e9d015e8c584bb2d278e25f0ccb27b) shows you all the send transactions of [LLL tokens](https://github.com/benjaminion/LLL_erc20) from my account (two transactions).

Here, your `X` (the token) is represented by the token's contract address, which is easy enough to find out for the various tokens.

As always, the API will return you a maximum of 10000 results, so you may need to manage `fromBlock` and `toBlock` accordingly.

Comment: this is insightful, why do I get the same API response whether topic1 is there or not, in your example. I would also like to know amounts of the transfer, I'm guessing this will be multiple calls

Comment: "why do I get the same API response whether topic1 is there or not, in your example." - because I'm the only person who has yet sent any of these tokens. Sorry, bad example :-)  " I would also like to know amounts of the transfer," - this is the `data` field of the JSON response; no multiple call needed.

Comment: Okay, so its a hex to decimal conversion in the data field. How do I know where the decimal is for a divisible contract unit?

Comment: "How do I know where the decimal is for a divisible contract unit?" - You need to call the (constant) `decimals()` function on the token contract. This will return the number of decimal place divisions set for the token, if it is ERC20 compliant. In my token it's 0; many tokens use 18 like Ether itself, so that 10^18 tokens = 1 whole unit.  It's only important as a presentational issue: token transfers etc. know nothing about this.

Comment: yes, I understand, I also need decimals for a presentational issue, like every other thing offchain lol.

Comment: @benjaminion how to get the signature for specified event and how to decode the data: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000032

Comment: Could you explain what is: signature of an ERC20 Transfer event.

Comment: @EnZo - The signature of an ERC20 Transfer event is keccak256("Transfer(address,address,uint256)") = 0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef. This format is part of the Ethereum [ABI specification](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI#events) (see `topics[0]`).

Comment: is there anyway this can be done with web3 1.0.0 beta @benjaminion ?

Comment: I'm also unsure on how to decode the "data" value. In the bscscan website  it shows an array. How can the string in the data be returned as an array?