# How do I checkout all the token transactions in a ether transaction using GETH?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, json-rpc

I create an erc20 contract on my private blockchain. Then I transfer some tokens from one accout to another. Now I can check on the new block and find that transaction like this:

```
{
  blockHash: "0x860ed4316ecd45b58e439f195a0312111c3e7ef73666d37f382ac2f64b2ce213",
  blockNumber: 3519,
  from: "0xecf6e8cbb8633a3c490d587fa357ad20e21d4b93",
  gas: 90000,
  gasPrice: 0,
  hash: "0xa4aedd34557884e977f0981ab55035527fd990efbee9115d2b37df51ee79180e",
  input: "0xa9059cbb00000000000000000000000089bb2b310f9379986972bc2940461540591a332d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000043c33c1937564800000",
  nonce: 13,
  r: "0x4b4a8cfb24766e96abfafd2197773e8816683afd7191bb8720e3445ad02ab70c",
  s: "0x69132b6f453aa23f2bd037d0a044b74d5dd1b4b0678af99e8581efc7f66cf8cd",
  to: "0xae4193c5100e173c123619fc2b3845e1091e1aa8",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0xa96",
  value: 0
}
```

but this doesn't show any information about the tokens I sent. Using `Transfer.watch` can get what I want like this:

```
  { address: '0xae4193c5100e173c123619fc2b3845e1091e1aa8',
  blockNumber: 3519,
  transactionHash: '0xa4aedd34557884e977f0981ab55035527fd990efbee9115d2b37df51ee79180e',
  transactionIndex: 0,
  blockHash: '0x860ed4316ecd45b58e439f195a0312111c3e7ef73666d37f382ac2f64b2ce213',
  logIndex: 0,
  removed: false,
  event: 'Transfer',
  args: 
   { from: '0xecf6e8cbb8633a3c490d587fa357ad20e21d4b93',
     to: '0x89bb2b310f9379986972bc2940461540591a332d',
     value: { [String: '2e+22'] s: 1, e: 22, c: [Array] } } }
```

I cannot check all the transactions through watch, and watch will not be always online. I want to check the transaction like etherscan.io:
[image]

What's the solution? Thank you!

Comment: Using geth, you mean directly the CLI? Or using something like Web3js?

Comment: both CLI and Web3js ^-^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this problem by reading [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24682/obtain-token-transfer-data-from-an-address)

let's start with the hash of the transaction. in geth ,we can use `getTransactionReceipt` to get detailed information:

```
    > eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x506fea5ae6d5bf08df79b3f2371b553c974a61ba9949225dac9a45017fd0d86d")
{
    blockHash: "0x2a5be303d5326d1004b9bcd840120648f898914f9b8e879b19d072bb19fd9434",
  blockNumber: 3511,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 53419,
  from: "0xecf6e8cbb8633a3c490d587fa357ad20e21d4b93",
  gasUsed: 53419,
  logs: [{
      address: "0xae4193c5100e173c123619fc2b3845e1091e1aa8",
      blockHash: "0x2a5be303d5326d1004b9bcd840120648f898914f9b8e879b19d072bb19fd9434",
      blockNumber: 3511,
      data: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000043c33c1937564800000",
      logIndex: 0,
      removed: false,
      topics: ["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef", "0x000000000000000000000000ecf6e8cbb8633a3c490d587fa357ad20e21d4b93", "0x00000000000000000000000089bb2b310f9379986972bc2940461540591a332d"],
      transactionHash: "0x506fea5ae6d5bf08df79b3f2371b553c974a61ba9949225dac9a45017fd0d86d",
      transactionIndex: 0
  }],
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000008000000000001000000001000000020000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000410000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000",
  status: "0x1",
  to: "0xae4193c5100e173c123619fc2b3845e1091e1aa8",
  transactionHash: "0x506fea5ae6d5bf08df79b3f2371b553c974a61ba9949225dac9a45017fd0d86d",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

`logs.topics[ 0 ]` is the hash of the token transaction; `logs.topics[ 1 ]` is the `from` address, and `logs.topics[ 2 ]` is the `to` address; and logs.data is the amount, you can copy data into console:

```
 > 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000043c33c1937564800000
2e+22
```

2e+22 is exactly the value i sent.